# Three.js part of video as texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to use part of a video as a texture in a Three.js mesh.

Video is here, http://video-processing.s3.amazonaws.com/example.MP4 it's a fisheye lens and I want to only use the part with actual content, i.e. the circle in the middle.

I want to somehow mask, crop or position and stretch the video on the mesh so that only this part shows and the black part is ignored.

Video code

```
var video = document.createElement( 'video' );
    video.loop = true;
    video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    video.preload = 'auto';
    video.src = "http://video-processing.s3.amazonaws.com/example.MP4";
    video.play();

var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
    texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

var material   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture } );
```

The video is then projected onto a 220 degree sphere, to give the VR impression.

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200,100,100, 0, 220 * Math.PI / 180, 0, Math.PI);
```

Here is a code pen
http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/vXBWGv

Can anyone let me know how I'm best to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to update the UV-Map of the sphere so that the relevant area of your texture is assigned to the corresponding vertices of the sphere.

The UV-coordinates for each vertex define the coordinates within the texture that is assigned to that vertex (in a range [0..1], so coordinates (0, 0) are the top left corner and (1,1) the bottom right corner of your video). [This example](http://threejs.org/examples/?q=ray#webgl_raycast_texture) should give you an Idea what this is about.

Those UV-coordinates are stored in your geometry as `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]` such that every vertex of every face has a `THREE.Vector2` value for the UV-coordinate. This is a two-dimensional array, the first index is the face-index and the second one the vertex-index for the face (see example).

As for generating the UV-map there are at least two ways to do this. The probably easier way (ymmv, but I'd always go this route) would be to create the UV-map using 3D-editing software like blender and export the resulting object using the three.js exporter-plugin.

The other way is to compute the values by hand. I would suggest you first try to simply use an orthographic projection of the sphere. So basically, if you have a unit-sphere at the origin, simply drop the z-coordinate of the vertices and use `u = x/2 + 0.5` and `v = y/2 + 0.5` as UV-coordinates.

In JS that would be something like this:

```
// create the geometry (note that for simplicity, we're 
//   a) using a unit-sphere and 
//   b) use an exact half-sphere)
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 18, 18, Math.PI, Math.PI)
const uvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];
const vertices = geometry.vertices;

// compute the UV from the vertices of the sphere. You will probably need 
// something a bit more elaborate than this for the 220degree FOV, also maybe
// some lens-distorion, but it will boild down to something like this:
for(let i = 0; i<geometry.faces.length; i++) {
  const face = geometry.faces[i];
  const faceVertices = [vertices[face.a], vertices[face.b], vertices[face.c]];

  for(let j = 0; j<3; j++) {
    const vertex = faceVertices[j];
    uvs[i][j].set(vertex.x/2 + 0.5, vertex.y/2 + 0.5);
  }
}
geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
```

(if you need more information in either direction, drop a comment and i will elaborate)

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to make this work but running into some JS errors "uvs[i].set is not a function" in Chrome http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/pEvbKy - what am I missing here!?

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. The `faceVertexUvs` have another dimension I hadn't in mind. It's basically this: `faceVertexUvs[uvSetIndex][faceIndex][faceVertexIndex]`. Will update my example accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I updated it with that and it resulted in a very small sphere very far away! http://codepen.io/bknill/pen/pEvbKy?editors=0010 I'll have a play

Comment: Unfortunately, the codepen just shows a black screen for me. But you might need to either adjust the camera-position (distance 100 compared to the sphere with size 1 is pretty far away), or scale the sphere up to it's previous size, something like `sphere.scale.set(100,100,100)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use texture.repeat to scale the texture

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Textures/Texture

for example, to scale 2x on both axis
texture.repeat.set(0.5, 0.5);

Comment: This is a good explanation of what you want I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803280/three-js-how-do-i-scaling-and-offset-my-image-textures